# What Conditions are needed for SignalR to work on a Windows mobile device?

Tags: windows-phone-8, signalr

I have a quick question regarding Signalr compatibility , according to Microsoft http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms, Windows Phone 8 should be supported . I created the small demo chat app that's found on most tutorials . I tested it on a iPhone and that works but I tried it on a Nokia Lumia 920(win8 phone) and while it displays, nothing is functional. 
The only thing included is J-Query & Signalr .

Is there anything specific I am overlooking, to get signalr to run on IE in a windows phone?, are there known issues for this?, hunted around but could not find any resources for troubleshooting this.

Comment: It should just work with on your lumia. Did you deploy the simple chat anywhere online? I can try hitting it with my lumia 920.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `SignalR` and it works just fine with Windows Phone 8 (I have the Nokia Lumia 920).  The problem is with IE's JavaScript support on the Windows Phone.  The `SignalR` chat demos use the JavaScript `prompt()` function and it is not supported on the Windows Phone browser.